# Using JsonPath to extract value without knowing key

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have a json string like this:

```
  "files": {
     "fileA.c": {
         "size": 100
     },
     "fileB.txt": {
         "size": 200
     }
  }
```

I want to extract the file names, {"fileA.c","fileB.txt"}, using [JsonPath](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/). Note that the number of files is unknown.

The problem is, I don't know whether the file name is a key or a value:

- If it is a key...well I certainly don't know the key name because that's the information I want to extract.
- If it is a value, then what is its key?
- Can I use JsonPath to extract the file names? If so, how?
- If JsonPath cannot do this, is there any Java library for Json that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, fileA.c and fileB.txt are keys, you can get them by iterating on the key in the enclosing object (which is referenced by the key "files").

I don't think JSONPath is really appropriate (or even applicable)  in this case, it is designed to access elements when you know the structure of the documents, which means that basically you know the keys. It would be much easier to simply use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to modify your data structure, to something like this;

```
var data = {
   "files": [
      {
         "name": "fileA.c",
         "size": 100
      },
      {
         "name": "fileB.txt",
         "size": 200
      },
      {
         "name": "fileC.txt",
         "size": 50
      }
   ]
};
```

When structured like this, you can use DefiantJS (http://defiantjs.com) to query for files which sizes are larger than 100...like this:

```
JSON.search(data, '//*[size >= 100]/name')
```

DefiantJS extends the global object JSON with the method "search", with which you can query JSON structure with XPath expressions.

To see a working example with your data, check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jRN22/